# Properties of an Ideal Transformer and the reasons behind them

Tags: transformer, coupling, reactance

Why should the  magnetising reactance of an ideal transformer be very large i.e. approach infinity? What practicality does  this imply?

Comment: Which reactances are you speaking of?

Comment: Reactances of both the Primary and the secondary coils i.e. L1, L2 and M where L1 is the reactance of Primary coil, L2 for secondary and M is mutual inductance

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have connected a transformer primary to an AC voltage source. There is no load connected in secondary.

In this scenario, you would ideally want no power to be consumed from the source. However, with a finite magnetising inductance this is not the case. According to faradays law, when a voltage is applied across a coil, a finite flux is established in the core. The establishment of flux requires energy in a non ideal material and that is manifested in the form of a current flowing from the source.

In short, in the non ideal world, the current flowing from the source has two components, one flowing to the load and the other flowing to establish flux in the core. The former component is captured in the circuit model of transformer as a magnetising inductance, although it is a non linear inductance which depends on the material properties.

Answer (score 0):

The magnetizing reactance is what you see looking into the transformer primary when the secondary winding is open circuited.  So this means that without a load on the secondary you see a high impedance looking into the primary.  The magnetizing reactance appears in parallel to the transformed impedance of the load you are going to place across the secondary, so you want it to be large.

Comment: What do you mean by transformed impedance and magnetizing reactance? Furthermore, why should seconda being open imply that primary has high impedance?

Answer (score 0):

An **Ideal** transformer has only one property, the turns ratio.

All other properties are ideal, that is either zero, or infinity.

No resistive or core losses, no magnetising current, no leakage inductance, able to sustain an arbitrary core flux.

When we come to model an ideal transformer with SPICE, then the way we communicate the turns ratio to the program is as the ratio of primary to secondary inductance, so we need to put finite figures in for those. If they are very large, then the magnetising current will be very small, which will usually do for a first approximation.

When we come to make a transformer form real materials, then all of these ideals have to yield to what's practical, and what we can afford. Things that were zero in the ideal transformer, we make as low as we can afford, things that were infinity we make as high as we can afford.

- Apart from silver (too expensive for general use) and superconductor (too difficult for general use) copper has the lowest resistance of all conductors, so we're stuck with using that, and accepting whatever resistive losses we get.
- Depending on the frequency, we use carefully engineered iron or ferrites, for high permeability, low hysteresis losses, and low eddy current losses.
- We generally want the magnetising current to be small, but there's no need to make it very small. It's in quadrature with the load current, so even if it's as high as 20% of the full load current, the increase in heating when the transformer is on full load is usually negligible. When a transformer is designed to run at light load for a long time, it's worth reducing it further for efficiency.
- Core saturation will limit the maximum voltage we can use, and copper cross section the maximum current.

Comment: You might also highlight that, in because of those listed properties, ideal transformers can work at any frequency up from and including DC. This is often overlooked